# css flexbox div to fill the available viewport height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My markup has the following structure:

```
<Header/>
<main style={{display: 'flex'}}>
   <div style={{flexGrow: 1}} id='one'>Left Panel</div>
   <div style={{flexGrow: 5}} id='two'>Main Content</div>  
</main>
```

Do not bother about `<Header />`. It is a React component that lies at the top of the page and has a certain height (not fixed). What I want is `div one` to take the entire height of the available viewport; that means `100vh` minus the height of the header that we do not know. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with display: flex, height:100vh, flex-flow: column and certainly margin : 0 on the body or parent container of your markup